# Dart - Is deconstruction the name of the feature that allows to build arrays from for or if statements

Tags: flutter, dart, language-features

Since not everything from dart is an expression ([Like Kotlin](https://kotlinlang.org/spec/control--and-data-flow-analysis.html#expressions-cdfa)) I wonder how it is possible that the next code runs:

### Example 1

I do a for loop that returns somehow each array item, it's like a deconstruction but with another syntax.

```dart
void main() {
  final numbers = [1, 2, 3];
  
  final computedNumbers = [for(final n in numbers) n];
  
  print(computedNumbers);
}
```

It prints: `[1, 2, 3]`

### Example 2

In Flutter you could build an array if ifs like:

```dart
[
  Text("My Text"),

  // Compiles fine
  if (myExpressionIsTrue) Text("Optional Text")
]
```

And at the end it creates a "deconstructed" array without the element if  `myExpressionIsTrue` is true. One thing that confuses me is that if I put the if with `{}` it does not compile, like this:

```dart
[
  Text("My Text"),
  if (myExpressionIsTrue) { // This fails at compile time
     Text("Optional Text") 
  }
]
```

## Question

The question is how it is possible that it works since `if` or `for` are not expressions, and what is the name of the language feature that allows this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The name of that feature is *collection for* and *collection if*.  See the [Lists section of the Dart Language Tour](https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour#lists).

I also highly recommend reading the article [Making Dart a Better Language for UI](https://medium.com/dartlang/making-dart-a-better-language-for-ui-f1ccaf9f546c), which discusses a lot of the considerations that went into the design of the feature.